# jquery code working in jsfiddle but not working in the browser

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I have a code on jsfiddle, it works fine but when i copy all the content and put it on a notepad then run on the browser, it doesn't work

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    nextSelector: '#slider-next',
    prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    nextText: 'Next &nbsp;-&nbsp; I am done!',
    prevText: 'I need to go back'
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/svnfv/)

Comment: When it doesn't work -- Are you running it from your local computer?

Comment: does it fires any error in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svnfv/2/)**

Try to put your `<script>` tag for initializing `bxSlider` after
the jQuery and your plugin, and also, wait for document ready:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            nextSelector: '#slider-next',
            prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
            infiniteLoop: false,
            nextText: 'Next &nbsp;-&nbsp; I am done!',
            prevText: 'I need to go back'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: does not work, the CSS is working fine, Jquery and JS have a problem. Did you test the code out of jsfiddle?

Comment: [here is the code i put in my browser!](http://snipplr.com/view/71457/slider/)

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala I think that you are viewing your page with `file:///` (you double click on the html file). Add jQuery with `http://`, see my updated answer :)

Comment: what change did you make? It is still not working, is it working in your browser?(not fiddle)

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala Yes, it correctly work me in my own HTML file (not jsfiddle), add the jQuery script tag with this: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` (you are properly add it like `src="//..."`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose your script in `$(function(){})` for it to work in browser

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        infiniteLoop: false,
        nextText: 'Next &nbsp;-&nbsp; I am done!',
        prevText: 'I need to go back'
    });
});
```

Fiddle adds the `$(function(){})` or the `$(document.ready()());` wrapper for you. Whereas, in the browser, we need to add it explicitly, hence the issue.

Comment: wait, i will try it out and tell you if it works

Comment: it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you included the script after the declaration of the jquery library? ALso, do you see any console log errors ?

Comment: In OP's case fiddle added an `onLoad` handler, which unlike jQuery's `.ready` can't simply be ignored by putting the code at the bottom of the body section. Not that it should really matter in OP's case.

Comment: it still doesn't work, can you show me the html that will work on the browser?

Comment: How is your script declared? Can you create a new fiddle with the entire html ?

Comment: here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/bQM9s/)

Comment: are you getting 404s in the console ?

Comment: so you need to fix that first.

Comment: yes i am getting 404s on the log

Comment: put them in a folder called `resources` and reference them relative to the `html` file. OR - prepend `http://` to all the urls

Comment: now only the CSS is working

Comment: put all the external resources in a local folder and add relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle attaches the jQuery library for you, and also wraps the code in the document.ready event - see the panel on the left. You have to do this yourself when you copy the code.

So, include the jQuery library. You can place your script at the bottom of the page (just before the closing BODY tag) rather than using the document.ready event.

**Note**: $(function(){ is equivalent to document.ready.

Comment: SO what do you suggest i do to make it work properly?

Comment: this is what my code looks like after following your instructions- 
http://pastehtml.com/view/d4zs0s626.html

Comment: it still doesn't work, can you show me the html that will work on the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Have you referenced the jQuery library in your HTML document? This needs to be at the top of every page that contains jQuery.

Put this in the `<head>` tags of your document (actually, it can go anywhere in the document but it must go before the jQuery code):

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The jQuery code can either be stored in an external file and referenced like the jQuery library above or it can be included in this document between script tags, like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            nextSelector: '#slider-next',
            prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
            infiniteLoop: false,
            nextText: 'Next &nbsp;-&nbsp; I am done!',
            prevText: 'I need to go back'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work for me, did you test it on a browser?